# NPM Pack doesn't update all files in the second project

Tags: react-typescript, npm-pack

I am creating a npm package using TypeScript and React. To test it I use second testing project by using commands: `npm run build` `npm pack`. In the second project I do `npm unistall PACKAGE`  `npm i PACKAGE_FILE.tgz`

The Package has 3 files, two of them are frequently changing: index.tsx, FormGroup.tsx. When I update the code, index.tsx file shows updates perfectly, while FormGroup.tsx does not. It still has the same code when I first installed it in the Testing Project.

I tried to google it, but no luck

I viewed following places, and see that the new version is there:

1. FormGroup.js in an unpacked PACKAGE_FILE.tgz
2. FormGroup.js file in node_modules/PACKAGE/dist

[code in node_modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8RcA.png)

But Chrome doesn't show any updated code in the source tab:

[code in Chrome Source tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbSUi.png)

Thank you in advance

Some source code:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "include": ["src", "__tests__/index.test.js", "babel.config.js", "__tests__/FormGroup.test.js"], /* Include only the src directory */
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "target": "es2016" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
    "declaration": true /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/index.js"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --env=jsdom --coverage --silent",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean",
    "build": "tsc",
    "preversion": "npm run build",
    "version": "npm publish"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.23.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.55",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.5",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: This may sound like a stupid question, but it pays to tick off those checkboxes: did you make sure your browser didn't just use a cached version of your built project? Try reloading with cache clear (ctrl + shift + r), or opening the page in an incognito tab, and see if the new code is there

Comment: I don't use npm link because I read that it is not the same as using package in production build

Comment: Yeah, I tried to clear cache and restart the page. Still doesn't update

Comment: one more quick thing to check: did you update the version number of your first package? If the version number is the same in the package.json, the build process might use cached code from the old one because it thinks it's still the same